# Looking for a celestial body that weights ~$10^{17} kg$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am exploring the outcome of a problem assigned in a quantum mechanics homework where the mass of of some beam of "something" is insignificant to the result. So much so that something weighing approximately $1.2285 * 10^{17} kg$ would be needed to make a difference in respect to the problem. (that is, assuming I've solved the problem correctly).

I have been googling for quite a bit and I can't find anything that is in the $10^{17} kg$ range. Does anything come to mind?

(I can't seem to find any good tags for this question)..

Comment: A few [asteroids and planetary satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Solar_System_objects_by_size#From_20_to_50_km) are in that ballpark.

Comment: @MikeG that works! I chose Prometheus, a moon of Saturn. If you would like, post it/that link as answer and I will accept it. Though, this question honestly does not provide much to the site. I might delete it instead.

Comment: Thats a diameter question. 1m3 rock is 5 tons - 5000kg. 1km3 is 5bn kg.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(mass) is actually pretty helpful (and lists Ceres as a body w/ mass 10^18kg, about 10 times what you asked, but providing a hint to the answer)